# PHP-Function suddently has errors with special characters

Tags: php, function, symfony, special-characters

## Background

I am currently testing to develop a small website.
A small function that i have created and that worked fine all the time suddently creates some trouble.
I figured already out that it is related to special characters.

### System

- Homebrew
- MacOS  --> I had a minor macOS-update in the last week.
- localhost
- Symfony5

### Issue

```
    public function slugify(string $value) : string {

        // for testing:
        $value = "<TEST1/>";   // <-- no error
        $value = "<TEST1/ß>";  // <-- ERROR
        $value = "<TEST1/ä>";  // <-- ERROR
        $value = "<TEST1/ö>";  // <-- ERROR

        dump($value);

        $value = strtolower($value);    // small letters

        $replaceArray = [
            ">" => "",
            "<" => "",
            " " => "-",
            "/" => "-",
            "ß" => "ss",
            "ä" => "ae",
            "ö" => "oe",
            "ü" => "ue",

        ];
        foreach ($replaceArray as $from => $to) {
            $value = str_replace($from, $to, $value);
        }

        dump($value);

        return $value;
    }
```

***Error-Msg***

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "name" 
for route "app_welcome_index" must match "[^/]++" ("test1-�" given) to generate a 
corresponding URL.").
```

***Question***

Maybe my Homebrew-Webserver (apache/httpd) has been replaced by the standard one from apple?!?! But I have no idea how to verify this.
Or any other ideas what might have happened?

Cheers
Tim

Comment: When dealing with multibyte characters, you should use the `mb_` prefixed functions in PHP, such as `mb_strtolower()`

Comment: Also, instead of looping over your replacements, you can simply do `$value  = str_replace(array_keys($replaceArray), $replaceArray, $value);` as the `str_replace()` (which should handle multibyte characters) is able to handle arrays of replacing pairs.

Comment: COOOL. It works again [with `mb_strtolower()`]. But no idea, why the 'old version' was fine up to now... anyway. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above, you should be using the `mb_*` prefixed functions in PHP where they exist when dealing with multibyte characters. We can also clean up and simplify the code a little, by doing it all in one line and in one go - no need to iterate over the replacement-array, as `str_replace()` can handle arrays which replaces key/value pairs.

```php
public function slugify(string $value) : string 
{
    $replaceArray = [
       ">" => "",
       "<" => "",
       " " => "-",
       "/" => "-",
       "ß" => "ss",
       "ä" => "ae",
       "ö" => "oe",
       "ü" => "ue",
    ];
    $value = str_replace(array_keys($replaceArray), $replaceArray, mb_strtolower($value));
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks again! The `mb_*`-trick solved my issue. Your aggregation tip is also nice! But I like to keep the loop to understand my code in later times ;-)